# C# datagrid ShortcutsEnabled

Tags: c#, datagrid

Is it possible to turn of the menu that shows up when you right clicking the active cell? When you have a textbox you can turn off this off with the ShortcutsEnabled. But for the datagridView i can't find it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the thing i was looking for to replace the default contextmenu with a custom contextmenu:

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the PreviewMouseRightButtonUp and set e.Handled = true in it

Comment: i'm just learning C# but were can you find PreviewMouseRightButtonUp?

Comment: It should be in your datagrid properties (in design mode select it, then press F4, or just left click -> properties), in the "Even handlers" section (the button with a lightning symbol)